# Prevent resizing of child element in Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

When an `Image` whose source is set to a web graphic is *programmatically* placed inside a `Grid`, it is auto-sized to fit the entire Grid.

How can I preserve the `Image`'s original proportions ?

Comment: prevent resizing or preserve proportions?

Comment: @MickyDuncan I considered them synonymous but preserve proportions I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent changing size of your image you need to set property `Strech` like this:

```
<Image Stretch="None"/>
```